# How to set SPC to act as Enter in minibuffer mode?

Tags: emacs, space, minibuffer

When I edit in minibuffer mode,  I must press Enter  to exit minibuffer.

But I prefer to use Space.

1. "Space" completes word again and again.
2. When the message is "Sole Completion", press Space to exit minibuffer.

Defaullt Space key in the second step cannot exit minibuffer, I remap it , but it not works at all.

(define-key minibuffer-local-map (kbd "SPC") `minibuffer-complete-and-exit)

any idea？

Comment: What version of Emacs are you using? I tried it with a blank 23.3.1 (`emacs -Q`) and it worked fine (at least completion).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Need to define a key in the  *minibuffer-local-completion-map*:

```
(define-key minibuffer-local-completion-map (kbd "SPC") 'minibuffer-complete-and-exit)
```